# What to look for in projectors to use in murals

Tags: tools, hardware-recommendation

To paint murals we will use an old 20th century overhead projector and transparencies to project images on a wall and draw preliminary outlines. Bulbs for the projector are getting hard to find. I'm thinking of getting a projector to hook onto my Mac Powerbook and project images from my computer.

Are there other muralists who use computer projectors? I'm hoping to get advice in what to look for in the projector I plan to purchase.

Answer (score 1):

I think that depends on the average size of your mural work and lighting conditions.

For larger murals and less than ideal conditions, you will probably need something with a lot of lumens.

I found an article that might help you decide on a good projector (I tried to look for an article that wasn't sponsored by any particular brand, but I would still verify this is an impartial article)
[Article Here](https://reactual.com/home-theater/best-projectors-outdoors-large-venues.html).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the size and lighting, as Tony said. Projectors are  compared using four main factors: brightness, resolution, aspect ratio and weight.

Once these factors have been considered, you can narrow down choices having on account other factors such as contrast ratio, inputs and outputs, warranty, lamp life etc.
As you plan on using your projector on different places you might need to consider its weight. A lighter, more portable one -around 1 or 2 kg- will be better.

About aspect ratio most projectors, whether they are 4:3, 16:10 or 16:9, are compatible with other aspect ratios, but it´s not recommended to use a projector in a format other than its native aspect ratio as it will stretch or compress the image or it will miss parts of the picture. The best aspect ratio depends on the source. 4:3 is most of the times the best for using with computers. This depends on the aspect ratio of the computer you´re using, anyway.

Projectors work scaling different resolutions, converting different input resolutions to the native output resolution. 
Scaling causes a loss of picture quality, tho. This happens not only when the projector´s resolution is lower than the source but when the projector´s resolution is higher too. Therefore you should match the projector resolution to the source's resolution.
Brightness is important. If you´re gonna use the projector on bright places you should choose one over 3000 lumens. Same for contrast ratio; the higher, the better for brighter places. Make sure the inputs and outputs are compatible with your computer too.

Comment: I got an Epson projector which has been serving me well. Your advice "Make sure the inputs and outputs are compatible with your computer too." is sound advice. Hooking the projector to my MacBookPro was a frustrating process of trial and error. I remember when plugging stuff to the Macbook was easy. Now I'm calling my once beloved Mac platform "Dongle Hell".

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends upon your demand, what kind of your mural work? what are the conditions of lightning? whether you need the daylight projector or normal HD Projector? what is the distance covered to project the image?

Lumens rate is one of the main factors when u decided to choose any good projector that full filed your requirements, resolution and aspect ratio also consider before buying an outdoor projector.

You can also consider the reliability, portability, cost, zoom range, contrast ratio, connectivity and many other factors. you can check [this article](https://nonstopbest.com/best-outdoor-projectors/) for these details, I am sure this will helps you a lot to choose the best projector for your setup.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Please note that whenever you link to your own blog, you must explicitly state so; see this [Help Center article](/help/promotion).